# jquery not get row id

Tags: jquery, html, events

i have the next code in html

```
<tr id='1'>
<td>'
   <a href='#'><i class='icon-pencil'></i></a> 
   <a href='#myModal' role='button' data-toggle='modal'><i class='icon-remove' ></i></a>
></td>
</tr>
```

and the next code in javascript code

```
$("a").click(function () {
    var id = $(this).closest("tr").attr('id');
    console.log(id);
});
```

but not works, for get the row id

EDIT:
i put the next function out of $(document).ready(function ()

```
function getId(idd) 
{
  var id = $(idd).closest("tr").attr('id');
}
```

and add onclick='getId(this);' to .
Is not the best method, but works.

PD: and i have the tag table, mi fault for no put the full code

Comment: What's with the quote here `<td>'` and angle bracket here `></td>`?

Answer (score 0):

Seems it's not going to work without a `<table>` tag.

Before - http://jsfiddle.net/UrYEG/
After - http://jsfiddle.net/UrYEG/1/